# Conditional injection using spring.net

Tags: inversion-of-control, spring.net

I want to be able to inject a property based on a condition using SPRING.NET. Lets say I have two objects A and B and based on the value of a property that I evaluate in code I want to be able to inject A when it is true and inject B when the property value is false. Can I do that in spring.net?

```
<object id="Service" singleton="false" type="comp.Service, comp.Service">
// if(p1 == true) p1 is calculated in code.
 <property name="_factory" ref="factory1" />
 // else
 <property name="_factory" ref="factory2" />
</object>

 <object name="factory1" type="comp.Factory1, Factory1">
      </object>

 <object name="factory2" type="comp.Factory2, Factory2">
      </object>
```

Comment: In Spring this is possible with the profiles functionality, see here http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/, but i don't find the equivalent in the .net version

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Use the expression:

```
<object id="Service" singleton="false" type="comp.Service, comp.Service">
    <property name="_factory" expression="(p1 ? @(factory1) : @(factory2))" />
</object>
```

you may want to read documents about [spring expression](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html), it's a big topic.